# Unable to find the file when remote connecting on ibm i using native strsql

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I have been trying to connect to my prod server from my dev using

connect to remote (which gets connected)

I am then trying to query a file in one particular library which exists on the remote server and is queryable on my server.

i am using the set current schema  to set the library to the required one.which sets it

However i am unable to query the file

error code sqlcod -204 ,sqlstte 42704

I am using the *sys naming convention.

My seq of operation
connect to prod uysing login works 
set current schema ='lib"  works 
select current_schema from sysibm.sysdummy1 works
select * from lib/file  :file i nlib *n not found sqlcode -204

Thanks

Comment: Can you add to the problem description if you have *USE permission to the Library, *USE permission on NULLID, and *USE or higher on the requested file?  Thanks.

Comment: I do have *use permission on library/file both since i can query the file on prod and id's are same across enviornments.

Comment: Does it work if you use the *sql naming convention? The fact that you /can/ access sysibm.sysdummy1 (note full stop not slash) is interesting.

Comment: yes it works with *sql naming

Comment: It's not an authority problem, then. Why can't you just use *sql, to get the job done?

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet. Where are you doing the connecting from? Is is ACS, STRSQL, or in a program? Is this production code or are you running diagnostics?

If you just want to query prod and your server is in the RDBDIRE, you can simply use the full qualification for the select statement (and any other statement for that matter). Just be aware that if the data is stored on a different IASP, that the connection needs to be defined with that new IASP in mind.

```
Select * from <server>.<library>.<file>;
```

If I am off-base here, please let me know what kind of code you're running that is using connect.